# intercept the Swagger /api-docs call and customize the response by adding extra meta data

Tags: json, swagger, customization, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using SpringFox Swagger 2 in my SpringBoot Application. I need to added some extra meta data in the swagger documentation for all of my models. So, I was thinking to intercept the Swagger document before it's returned in the response of /api-docs, to manually customize the JSON object/swagger file, and add extra metadata for the model.

Is this the right direction? Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found some solution, I am wanting to do a similar thing. thanks